# SCALA - Computing Quandratics and Getting Complex numbers

Tags: scala, math, complex-numbers, negative-number, quadratic

Just a quick question, I have a scala code which finds the roots of a quadratic equation. The problem I am having is printing out multiple answers and getting answers with complex numbers.

PS: I am in the first few weeks of my Scala course so I only know the bare basics.

```
val a = readDouble
val b = readDouble
val c = readDouble
if(b*b-4.*a*c > 0) //I have this to deal with the negatives :( {
val root1 = (-b + math.sqrt(b*b-4.*a*c)) / (2*a)
val root2 = (-b - math.sqrt(b*b-4.*a*c)) / (2*a)
println(root1 + " " root2)
}
else 
println("No root")
```

Thanks friend!

Comment: Perhaps you can supply an example of the output? Also missing a + sign here + " " root2)

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: I want to print answers that contain complex numbers and multiple answers. Right now, I only get one answer when it is positive.

Comment: Just stick it in a while-loop....?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should put your result in a Set, because:

- There can be multiple results, so it must be some collection
- You don't want to have duplicates and Set elimintates them for you

So something like this should work:

```
def roots(a : Double, b : Double, c: Double)= {
  if (b*b-4.0*a*c >= 0) {
     Set(1,-1).map(-b + _ * math.sqrt(b*b-4.0*a*c))
  }else{
     Set()
  }
}

val a = readDouble
val b = readDouble
val c = readDouble

println(roots(a,b,c))
```

With this function, you can get the following results:

```
scala> roots(2,3,4)
res4: scala.collection.immutable.Set[_ <: Double] = Set()

scala> roots(-2,3,4)
res5: scala.collection.immutable.Set[_ <: Double] = Set(3.4031242374328485, -9.403124237432849)

scala> roots(2,0,0)
res6: scala.collection.immutable.Set[_ <: Double] = Set(0.0)
```

For complex numbers, you can use [spire](https://github.com/non/spire). Just change the code above a little bit:

```
import spire.implicits._
import spire.math._

def roots(a : Complex[Double], b : Complex[Double], c: Complex[Double]) =
     Set(1,-1).map(-b + _ * (b*b-4.0*a*c).sqrt)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is a high school maths problem more than a Scala problem. There are always 2 roots in a quadratic equation (your maths is for a quadratic equation). If the b*b-4*a*c term is negative, then the answer is complex (of the form a + i*b) and one should note there are still 2 roots. If this term is zero, there are two roots that have the same value and always real. If the term is positive, you have two distinct real valued roots. Handling [complex](http://schools-wikipedia.org/wp/c/Complex_number.htm) numbers in Scala can be achieved as shown [here](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/02/complex-numbers-in-scala.html).